# Groovy-Eclipse JPA annotation code completion

Tags: eclipse, groovy, groovy-eclipse

I am using

- Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit os
- eclipse-jee-luna-R-linux-gtk-x86_64 (fresh download and unzipped)
- Installed Groovy-Eclipse plugin snapshot - 
  http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.4/

I am getting code completion option for @Column when I type @Colu **ctrl+space**

but I don't see name option when I type @Column(na **ctrl+space**

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA groovy support is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a defect. I raised http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1791 for this.